# Python style: catching exceptions just to print them

Tags: python, exception, styles, pep8

I'm not that experienced with error handling in Python and was wondering, in terms of style, is it worth catching and printing errors that would be raised anyway if you don't explicitly handle it in the code?

For example:

```
my_func(path):
    try:
        some_func_that_opens_file(path) # this would raise and IOError by itself
    except IOerror as ex:
        print ex  # or alternatively print 'your file doesn't exist'
```

Or is the purpose of try/except rather catching an error and proceeding to do something else in spite of the error (where the program would otherwise fail)? E.g.:

```
my_func(path):
    try:
        some_func_that_opens_file(path) # this would raise and IOError by itself
    except IOerror:
        fixed = fix_path(path) # makes the path what it needs to be
        some_func_that_opens_file(fixed)
```

I searched a fair bit before asking this so hopefully my question isn't redundant.

Thank you!

Comment: If you are catching the error  it won't be raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You handle exceptions to have your code continue; the alternative is to have the default handler (just before interpreter exit) print a traceback.

You handle exceptions that are *not* errors in your code; sometimes it is more efficient to handle exceptions than it is to test for the possibility that an exception will occur. This is called *asking for forgiveness* as opposed to *asking for permission*.

Take collecting information in lists in a dictionary for example. You could use:

```
if key not in dictionary:
    dictionary[key] = ['default', 'initial', 'value']
listval = dictionary[key]
listval.extend(['other', 'values'])
```

That'd be asking for permission, while:

```
try:
    listval = dictionary[key]
except KeyError:
    listval = dictionary[key] = ['default', 'initial', 'value']
listval.extend(['other', 'values'])
```

would be asking for forgiveness. This uses exception handling explicitly; if the case where the key is missing is the *exception* (not common), asking for forgiveness is *faster* than asking for permission.

If the error is on the part of the end user and can be anticipated, you also need to handle exceptions as your program stopping with an ugly traceback is not user friendly.

But exceptions thrown through incorrect use of an API should not be caught; such incorrect use is indicative of a bug in the code somewhere, and you as a developer then really want to know what went wrong, and where.